# Are there some regulations limiting how loud in-flight announcements can be?

Tags: air-travel, health, regulations

I am sometimes surprised at how loud some in-flight announcements are in some flights. Are there some regulations on how loud in-flight announcements can be?

Comment: I don’t think this question deserves to be so heavily downvoted. I don’t think the author was asking about safety warnings

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The U.S. Government Accountability Office (U.S. GAO) has a [report](https://www.gao.gov/assets/gao-18-109r.pdf) on interior aircraft noise:

[image]

However, it seems there are no regulations on how loud in-flight announcements can be:

> As part of FAA’s airworthiness standards, FAA requires that cockpit noise and vibration levels not interfere with the safe operation of the aircraft and that public address system announcements are audible by the cabin’s occupants. However, neither regulation dictates a specific noise exposure limit. FAA has issued guidance for airlines and manufacturers on recommended noise levels for cockpit and certain crew rest areas in order to reduce the effect of noise on crewmembers’
> sleep. In 2013, in response to a federal requirement, FAA issued a policy statement making OSHA’s noise exposure standard, among other OSHA standards, applicable to the working conditions of cabin crewmembers—but not pilots—on aircraft in operation.16 FAA and OSHA agreed that OSHA would respond to complaints through written and oral communication and would coordinate with FAA if workplace inspections were necessary.

I also couldn't find any regulations pertaining to public address systems on https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/apl/noise_emissions/aircraft_noise_levels/

Note that, unlikely what the existing answer by [DJClayworth](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/264/djclayworth) claims, regulations may set limit on alert loudness. E.g., for [fire alarm systems](https://www.ecmag.com/section/integrated-systems/fire-alarm-system-too-loud):

> To answer the principal’s questions, first I turned to the information provided in the annex of NFPA 72-2019, National Fire Alarm and Signaling Code. Annex A for Section 18.4.1.2 discusses the **maximum sound pressure level of 110 decibels (dBA)** permitted in a space. In the 2007 edition, this was reduced from 120 dBA in previous editions.

Comment: Did I say anything about fire alarm loudness? The question was about in-flight announcements. But I'm assuming you know that. And 110 decibels is the pain threshold.

Comment: @DJClayworth Your answer's logic (" you can be darn sure it will be loud enough to wake people up immediately.") applies to any emergency alarms/alerts.

Comment: Feel free to have an argument about this if you want, but please have it with somebody else.

Comment: @DJClayworth you asked a question, I answered it

Answer (score 2):

Obviously not. If nothing else when the pilot announces "fasten your seatbelt and adopt the brace position" you can be darn sure it will be loud enough to wake people up immediately.

Yes, there's probably a limit aimed at preventing damage to your eardrums if that's what you mean.

Comment: Thanks, yes by "Are there some regulations limiting how loud in-flight announcements can be?" I meant "is there a limit set by some regulations?".